# Is KL divergence $D(P||Q)$ strongly convex over $P$ in infinite dimension

Tags: pr.probability, convex-optimization, it.information-theory, convex-analysis, probability-distributions

By KL divergence I mean $D(P||Q) = \int dP \log(\frac{dP}{dQ})$. I am looking for the conditions under which this strong convexity is true and possible references. I could not find an answer for infinite dimensions. I am specifically interested in the case where the dimension is uncountable.

Note that this strong convexity is equivalent to the strong convexity of negative entropy function $H(P) = \int dP \log(dP)$.

Comment: See the proofs here -- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.2459.pdf -- they hold in infinite dimensions (though the paper formally deals with finite dimensions).

Comment: Which result in this paper are you referring to?

Comment: It suffices to prove the statement for the negative entropy $H(P) = \int dP log(dP)$. It seems that for $P$ and $Q$ with bounded negative entropy, $H(P)-H(Q)-\langle H'(Q), P-Q\rangle = KL(P||Q)$ (I am not sure if this equality could be proved for general $P$ and $Q$). With this equality, one can use  Pinsker's inequality to derive the lower bound $H(P)-H(Q)-\langle H'(Q), P-Q\rangle \geq \frac{1}{2}\|P-Q\|_1^2$. But this does not prove the strong convexity unless one knows that on the space of possible $P$ and $Q$'s there is a fixed lower bound on the H. No fixed upper bound on $H$ is needed.

Comment: In the problem that I was working on, the set of $P$'s comes from transport plans between two marginal distributions $p$ and $q$ with bounded entropy. Thus, the lower bound is obvious and the set of bounded entropy $P$'s could be convex. So, it seems that above argument could be used to prove strong convexity of negative entropy on the convex set of tranports with bounded H.

Comment: See Theorem 11 in the paper I linked.

Comment: But that only proves strict convexity at best. I’m looking for strong convexity.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you know that this holds in finite dimensions?

Comment: yes. In finite dimension it is true.

Comment: If the coefficient of strong convexity doesn’t depend on the dimension, it should carry over to infinite dimensions.

Comment: The coefficient does not depend on the dimension. But it is not obvious to me why it should be true. Do you know of any references?

Comment: Why can't you argue the convexity of negentropy by continuity, at least in the case of countable dimension? Approximate a distribution $P$ with countable support by truncating to $P_n$ with support of size $n$. The entropy limits should work, no?

Comment: I am interested in the uncountable case. Plus, I do not follow your argument here.

Comment: @MaziarSanjabi, regarding the characaterization of KL-divergence above, how do you define an inner product over the infinite dimensional space of measures (not in general a Hilbert space and not even a Banach one) ?  You can still use another defintion of strong convexity which can be adapted to metric spaces.

Comment: Moreover your KL divergence is defined only over the set of measures that are absolutely continuous w.r.t. Q; Similar care is required for the definition of entropy  for general measures (what is $dP$ inside the logarithm for example in case of singular measures?)

Comment: @Arash You can assume that we are only considering $P$'s that are absolutely continuous with respect to a fixed measure $Q$.
I believe the strong convexity, if true, would be with respect to $1$-norm which is not a Hilbertian norm (does not come from an inner product).

Comment: @MaziarSanjabi can you point me to a proof that negentropy is strongly convex infinite dimensions? Then I can try to work out a proof for the countable (and maybe even continuous) case.

Comment: Can you give references to the fact that you mentioned that the KL divergence is strongly convex in $P$ in finite dimensions?

Comment: I have not seen any satisfactory proof that would be as general as your proof. All the arguments in the literature follow the lines of proof provided here: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~yaoliang/mynotes/sc.pdf
Note that it only proves the strong convexity on the relative interior of the probability simplex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\newcommand{\de}{\delta}
\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$

Take any probability measures $P_0,P_1$ absolutely continuous with respect (w.r.) to $Q$. 
We shall prove the following:

> **Theorem 1.** For any $t\in(0,1)$,
>   \begin{align*} \De:=(1-t)H(P_0)+tH(P_1)-H(P_t)  
> \ge\frac{(1-t)t}2\,\|P_1-P_0\|^2, 
> \end{align*}
>   where $\|P_1-P_0\|:=\int|dP_1-dP_0|$ is the total variation norm of $P_1-P_0$, 
>   \begin{equation*}
>  H(P):=D(P||Q)=\int \ln\frac{dP}{dQ}\,dP,
> \end{equation*}
>   and, for any elements $C_0,C_1$ of a linear space, $C_t:=(1-t)C_0+tC_1$. 
>   Thus, by ["A third definition[8] for a strongly convex function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions), indeed $D(P||Q)$ is strongly convex in $P$ w.r. to the total variation norm.

We see that the lower bound on $\De$ does not depend on $Q$.

*Proof of Theorem 1.* Take indeed any $t\in(0,1)$. Let $f_j:=\frac{dP_j}{dQ}$ for $j=0,1$, so that $f_t=\frac{dP_t}{dQ}$. By [Taylor's theorem with the integral form of the remainder](https://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/141/remainder.pdf), for $h(x):=x\ln x$ and $j=0,1$ we have
\begin{equation*}
 h(f_j)=h(f_t)+h'(f_t)(f_j-f_t)+(f_j-f_t)^2\int_0^1 h''((1-s)f_t+sf_j)(1-s)\,ds,
\end{equation*}
whence 
\begin{align*}
 \de&:=(1-t)h(f_0)+th(f_1)-h(f_t) \\ 
 &=(1-t)t\,(f_1-f_0)^2\,
 \int_0^1\Big(\frac t{(1-s)f_t+sf_0}+\frac{1-t}{(1-s)f_t+sf_1}\Big)(1-s)\,ds \\ 
 &=(1-t)t\,(f_1-f_0)^2\,
 \int_0^1\Big(\frac t{f_{u_0(t,s)}}+\frac{1-t}{f_{u_1(t,s)}}\Big)(1-s)\,ds, 
\end{align*}
where 
$$u_j(t,s):=(1-s)t+js.$$ 
So,
\begin{equation}
 \De=\int\de\,dQ=(1-t)t\,\int_0^1(1-s)\,ds\,[tI(u_0(t,s))+(1-t)I(u_1(t,s))], \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation*}
 I(u):=\int\frac{(f_1-f_0)^2}{f_u}\,dQ. 
\end{equation*}
Next, take any $u\in(0,1)$. Then $P_1$ is absolutely continuous w.r. to $P_u$. Introducing
$g_u:=\dfrac{dP_1}{dP_u}=\dfrac{f_1}{f_u}$, we have 
\begin{multline*}
 I(u)=\frac1{(1-u)^2}\,\int\frac{(f_1-f_u)^2}{f_u}\,dQ
 =\frac1{(1-u)^2}\,\int(g_u-1)^2\,dP_u \\ 
 \ge\frac1{(1-u)^2}\,\Big(\int|g_u-1|\,dP_u\Big)^2
 =\frac1{(1-u)^2}\,\|P_1-P_u\|^2=\|P_1-P_0\|^2. \tag{2}
\end{multline*}
Note also that for any $t\in(0,1)$ and $s\in(0,1)$ we have $u_0(t,s)\in(0,1)$ and $u_1(t,s)\in(0,1)$ and hence, by (2), $I(u_j(t,s))\ge\|P_1-P_0\|^2$ for $j=0,1$. 
Now Theorem 1 follows by (1).

*Remark.* The constant factor $\frac12$ in the lower bound in Theorem 1 is the best possible one.
Indeed, assuming that $P_1$ is absolutely continuous w.r. to $P_0$ and introducing $f:=\frac{dP_1}{dP_0}$, after some rather straightforward manipulations we get 
\begin{equation}
 \De=\int k(t,f)\,dP_0, \tag{*}
\end{equation}
where $\De$ is as before and 
\begin{equation}
 k(t,f):=t f \ln f-(1-t+t f)\ln(1-t+t f). 
\end{equation}
Take now any $h\in(0,1)$ and let $f$ take values $1-h,1+h$ each on a set of $P_0$-measure $1/2$, so that $\|P_1-P_0\|=h$. Then, in view of (*), for each $t\in(0,1)$, 
\begin{equation}
\De=\frac12\,k(t,1-h)+\frac12\,k(t,1+h)\sim \frac{(1-t)t}2\,h^2=\frac{(1-t)t}2\,\|P_1-P_0\|^2 
\end{equation}
as $h\downarrow0$, which confirms the optimality claim.

Comment: I have added a remark on the optimality of the lower bound.

Comment: So the absolute continuity of $dP_1$ and $dP_2$ w.r. to each other seems to be absolutely necessary for the proof (without it the Taylor expansion would fail, right?).
In the problem that motivated my question on this, $dP_1$ and $dP_2$ are optimal solutions to the following optimization (assuming everything is well behaved):
$P_i = \arg\min_{P} \int (C_i~dP) + \lambda KL(P||Q)$ (subject to some other constraints on the marginals of $P$). And I am not sure if it would be possible to make sure the $P_1$ and $P_2$  would be absolutely continuous w.r.t each other.

Comment: And also why is this inequality true: $u(t):=\frac1{f_{2t/3}}+\frac1{f_{(2t+1)/3}}\ge(1-t)u(0)+tu(1)$

Comment: The inequality for $u(t)$ went the wrong way. Now this is fixed, albeit the new lower bound is slightly worse, and the proof is now more complicated. As for the mutual absolute continuity condition for $P_0$ and $P_1$, I believe it can be rather easily removed by approximation, say by adding small positive constants to the densities $f_0$ and $f_1$ and then renormalizing to keep the condition $\int f_j\,dQ=1$.

Comment: The previous, better (and optimal) bound is now restored. The proof is greatly simplified; computer algebra is no longer needed. Also, the mutual absolute continuity condition for $P_0$ and $P_1$ is no longer needed or used.

Comment: Are you sure about not needing the absolute continuity condition of $P_1$ and $P_0$ with respect to each other? Where was it exactly used previously and how is it not needed anymore? It is a bit curious as it is not clear to me if the strong convexity holds in the finite dimensions when $P_1$ and $P_2$ are not absolutely continuous wrt each other. Also could the end of the proof be simplified using Pinsker inequality?

Comment: The proof is now further simplified, distilled just to the original key ideas.

Comment: Concerning your questions: In the original proof, I had to deal with $\int\frac{(f_1-f_0)^2}{f_0}\,dQ$ and $\int\frac{(f_1-f_0)^2}{f_1}\,dQ$, and therefore I then made the technical assumption that $P_0$ and $P_1$ are absolutely continuous w.r. to each other. Now I only deal with $\int\frac{(f_1-f_u)^2}{f_u}\,dQ$ with $u\in(0,1)$, and for such $u$ the measure $P_1$ is always absolutely continuous w.r. to $P_u$. This is now made explicit in the answer as well. I don't see a way (or need) to further simplify the proof, by using Pinsker's inequality or by other means.

Comment: And, yes, the strong convexity does hold for probability measures on any measurable spaces, finite or not, and it holds whether or not $P_0$ and $P_1$ are absolutely continuous w.r. to each other. Indeed, none of these conditions were needed or used in the proof.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand the proof much better. One naive question though: at the beginning of the proof what happens to the lower bound on $\delta$ when $f_1=0$ but $f_0>0$. Does this cause any problem in the bound and the following results?

Comment: I don't see any lower bound on $\delta$ in the beginning of the proof, or anywhere in the proof. The only inequalities in the proof occur only at the very end of it, providing a lower bound (equal $\|P_1-P_0\|^2$) on $I(u)$ and, in particular, on $I(u_j(t,s))$. Anyhow, on the set where $f_1=0$ but $f_0>0$, we have $\delta=(1-t)t\,f_0^2\,\int_0^1\Big(\frac t{(1-u_0(t,s))f_0}+\frac{1-t}{(1-u_1(t,s))f_0}\Big)(1-s)\,ds=-(1-t)\ln(1-t)\,f_0$; I don't know if this helps in understanding the proof; please let me know.

Comment: Sorry, I meant equality. My question was: Does, in this case, the left-hand side value for $\delta$ equal the right-hand side value, i.e. the integral?

Comment: Yes, the equality holds, with the details just described in my previous comment.

Comment: oh, sorry. You are absolutely right. In my computations, I was using a wrong definition for $f_t$. Thank you so much for your help.